# How to add a name to a Marker

Tags: ros, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have searched extensively on all the tutorials but I cannot find out how to add a name to my Marker. I have a marker array and want to display different names on every marker in rviz. Does anyone have any idea how this can be done.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72844/how-to-add-a-name-to-a-marker/) by [Cristian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5869/cristian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-08-14

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cristian](https://answers.ros.org/users/5869/cristian/) on 2013-08-14**:
I think I have to use interactive markers in order to add names to all markers. Is there any other way to do it because I dont want to make an interactive marker server and interactive marker file in order to just add names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For each of your markers, you could publish another marker with type TEXT_VIEW_FACING at the same location as your original marker. As far as I know the TEXT_VIEW_FACING type displays the string in the marker.text field at the location specified in marker.pose.position.

Best Tim

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2013-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2